# How to send form data with Get method in axios?

Tags: axios, react-query

I want to call an api with GET method and pass some form data. But seem axios is not supporting the form data with GET. Is there any way for me to overcome this problem?

ps: I am using react query and axios

Comment: Are you sure of the GET method ? GET is not intended to post form data. You normally have to use POST or PUT HTTP methods

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a form data through GET request but you can customize the request's URL query parameters. Look at the code sample below.

```js
//assuming instance is your axios instance.

instance.get("/test",{params:{key:value, key1:value1}}).then((data)=>{}).catch((error)=>{})

//this will send a GET request to /test?key=value&key1=value1
```

GET request doesn't support form data but you can use URL query parameters. Just like I did above.

For more information about axios visit [axios npm package](https://npmjs.com/package/axios)